# alphabetical scrolling for WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying to look for an existing solution for creating a scroll bar for a list view or data grid that can allow alphabetical scrolling (scroll bar with alphabetical headings, like contact list in ios or android) in WPF - has anyone seen a solution like that?

If not - is the best way to approach this problem creating some sort of groupings and then have the scroll bar display the group headers?

thanks!

Comment: I will need the same functionality soon and I'm thinking of implementing it on my own by drawing on the adorner's layer.

Comment: Are you looking for a treeview

Comment: Tree View might work - but with a context sensitive scroll bar

Comment: Just another thought if anyone is down the same road as me - the "alphabetical scroll bar" might not be a scroll bar ... just a list of tags to jump to certain headers? (see the contact list in Outlook if you have one)

Comment: What do you want to happen when the user scrolls? Highlight the next letter?

Comment: no - it doesn't have to be that way ... could literally be like a bookmark